# delete multiple records in laravel using form submit

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I need to delete multiple user records, selected by multiple check boxes and then press delete and submit the form `userListform`.

1. In the view I have added anchor with javascript `deleteUser()`

```
<a href="javascript:void();" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="deleteUser();">Delete</a>
```

2. in the view

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/user/delete')}}" id="userListform" >
```

3. in the route

```
Route::post('/user/delete', 'UsersController@delete');
```

4. Delete function

```
function deleteUser(){    
    var $checkboxes = jQuery('#userListform input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkedItems = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;    
    if(checkedItems > 0){
        var status = confirm("Do you need to delete the user!!");   
        if (status == true) {                        
            document.getElementById("userListform").submit(); 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Please select the users to be deleted!");    
    }
}
```

I have successfully submited the form but i'm not getting to the delete function of the `usercontroller@delete` method , instead it is showing 404 error

Comment: please post your code

Comment: done . the chck boxes are array of   <input type="checkbox" name="user[]" value="{{$item->id}}">

Comment: please review the code once again

Comment: sorry yeah i saw them when i edited it, the formatting wasn't showing the code

Comment: could you post the full form code <form> ... </form> and also all of the delete method

Comment: also the deleteUser() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add csrf token in form,it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
in the view
<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.delete')}}" id="userListform" >

in the route
Route::post('/user/delete', 'UsersController@delete')->name('user.delete);
```